# iOS Switch to another ViewController/View after Login on LoginView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a LoginViewController with a LoginView. After pressing a login-button and a successful check of the login data i want show a navigationController.

I dont want to have the Navigation Controller Headline in the LoginView.

Can you give me some tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes use:

```
   myNavController.navigationBarHidden = true
```

Alternatively you can show your LoginViewController, and add the Navigation Controller to the view only after the login-button has been pressed.

Answer (score 1):

You could always try presenting the login view as a modal view controller over the initial navigation view. I have an app that does that, and it works quite well.