# UINavigationBar is showing after a push

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

I'm using storyboard for the UI and I have the following:

A login window which is the init view of the segue. If the login is succesfull it will take the user to another view which can't have the back button to the login page! This is a `UITabBarController` and it has its own navigation bar. Now it shows both navigation bars and the back button is present the whole app.

If I tap the back button it always takes me to the login view. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Switch to another ViewController/View after Login on LoginView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884160/ios-switch-to-another-viewcontroller-view-after-login-on-loginview)

Comment: not is not, as idont want to hide per se my nav bar. I have a custom bar for each view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happens when you have a navigationcontroller, which adds the status bar to every controller's view you segue way in, AND a own navigation bar for every controller's view.

a) just get rid of the dedicated navigation bar for the controller to segue way into

b) don't use the navigationcontroller and do modal pushes to the controller's views

```
[currentController presentModalViewController:controllerYouWantToShow animated:YES]
```

c) the the navigationcontroller's navbar, i wouldn't recommend that though, as it gives you strange behavior and really is brute force, just not the best way to go about it..

Comment: tried  b) but no luck! a) cant get rid of them as I need couple of buttons depending on which view its loaded. not sure what may be done here!

Comment: c) 

[currentController presentModalViewController:controllerYouWantToShow animated:YES];

Comment: I did that before but alol what I get was:“Application tried to present modally an active controller” because the login view its the first view to be shown

Comment: fixed :) changed the segues from push to modal and treated them as modal presentation instead a push. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to hide the whole bar?

If so:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

Or do you just want to hide the back button?

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:NO]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look to the left in storyboard mode to where your navigation controller is. You can delete the navigation bar if you dont want the back button or hide either one.

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

However there are better ways of doing a login screen than pushing onto the view controller stack which is what your doing with the nav controller.

A good way to do a login is presenting a modal view controller and then dismissing it without the navigation controller at all. This way you will never have the ability to navigate back to the login screen if you are already logged in. Just set a global boolean variable in the app delegate that allows the entire app to know you're logged in, and test that variable after you dismiss the modal login page.

That way you dont have several navigation controllers which you typically don't want

Cheers

Comment: Hi! ive tried by hiding it that way, but i just hide its own nav bar, and not the bar with the back button

Comment: I've had a lot of issue with navigation controllers too in my experience but you need to know when to use them and when not to. If you need to use two navigtion controllers to solve your problem, there's most likely a better way to do it. Think of modal transitions as popups like websites. A lot of the time on the web, login forms pop up, dismiss, then navigate the user to their profile or whatever. I think this might be what you're looking for instead of using two navigation bars. Hope this helps.

Comment: he is obviously not looking to have two bars

Comment: Exactly MJB, its like the nav stack its overlapping and I have both nav bars

Answer (score 0):

If you use a nav controller and a push segue, you're going to get a 'back' button because that's the nature of the navigation controller. It sounds like what you want ("which cant have the back button to the login page") is to reset the navigation controller's stack so that it doesn't include the login view controller. You should be able to do that with a custom segue (they're easy to write). Another option would be to present the login view controller modally, which is a pretty typical way to do a login screen.